# JS: export an Array.prototype

Tags: javascript

If I want to add a prototype to JavaScript's `Array`, is there a way to export it so that I can put all of the prototype methods in a file such as `modules/prototypes.js`

Would it be `export Array`? or would I add export prior to setting the prototype?

Comment: Modifiying the prototypal inheritance behavior of the built in `Array` is a really bad idea as it can interfere with so many operations further down the line.

Comment: @DMcCallum83 understood; nonetheless any idea how one _would_ do this?

Comment: I assume you don't mean "add a prototype", but rather "add a method to the prototype".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your code modifies the global `Array.prototype` object (hint: [it should not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/1048572)), you don't need to export anything. You just need to run it. You'd include the module that does this with

```
import "prototype/array.js";
```

but not get any particular imports. All arrays would simply inherit from the (now modified) global `Array.prototype`.

Comment: thank you for answering the question asked. I appreciate it, was just confused to the syntax as to how one _would_ do this, not that one should.

Comment: Not "all arrays you create", but "all arrays created in the past, present or future by you or anyone else (in this realm)".